# How to save scraped data to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, converters

I want to scrape website and put the desired data in to JSON file. The issue I'm countered is that I get a text and only can print it. But I need to add only specific data in JSON file and reuse data with my classes. the WEB I'm scraping and my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://lt.brcauto.eu/automobiliu-paieska/'

req = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

pages = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'page-item')[-2] #biggest page -2 ">" we need only before the last

cars_printed_counter = 0 

for number in range(1, int(pages.text)):
req = requests.get(URL + '?page=' + str(number))
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

if cars_printed_counter == 20:
    break

for single_car in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'cars-wrapper'):

    if cars_printed_counter == 20:
        break

    Car_Title = single_car.find('h2', class_ = 'cars__title')
    Car_Specs = single_car.find('p', class_ = 'cars__subtitle')
    

    print('\nCar number:', cars_printed_counter + 1)
    
    print(Car_Title.text)
    print(Car_Specs.text)


    cars_printed_counter += 1
```

The data I get looks like this: [Printed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWuol.jpg)

```
Car number: 19

BMW 520 Gran Turismo M-Sport

2013 | 2.0 Diesel | Automation | 255229 km | 135 kW (184 AG) | Black

Car number: 20

BMW 750 i Automation

2005 | 5.0 Gasoline | Automation | 343906 km | 270 kW (367 AG) | Grey
```

And the question is: How should I put the data into JSON file that it would look like this: [Desired json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lwk0.jpg)

```
[
{
    "fuel": "diesel",
    "title": "BMW 520 Gran Turismo M-Sport",
    "year": 2013,
    "run": 255229,
    "type": "Black"
},
{
    "fuel": "gasoline",
    "title": "BMW 750 i Automation",
    "year": 2005,
    "run": 343906,
    "type": "Grey"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight to the point:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

URL = 'https://lt.brcauto.eu/automobiliu-paieska/'

req = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

pages = soup.find_all('li', class_='page-item')[-2]  # biggest page -2 ">" we need only before the last

cars_printed_counter = 0

for number in range(1, int(pages.text)):
    req = requests.get(URL + '?page=' + str(number))
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

if cars_printed_counter == 20:
    break
out = []
for single_car in soup.find_all('div', class_='cars-wrapper'):

    if cars_printed_counter == 20:
        break

    Car_Title = single_car.find('h2', class_='cars__title')
    Car_Specs = single_car.find('p', class_='cars__subtitle')

    print('\nCar number:', cars_printed_counter + 1)

    print(Car_Title.text)
    print(Car_Specs.text)

    car = {}
    car["title"] = Car_Title.text
    subs = Car_Specs.text.split(' | ')
    car["year"] = subs[0]
    car["fuel"] = subs[1].split(" ")[1]
    car["run"] = subs[3].split(" ")[0]
    car["type"] = subs[5]
    car["number"] = cars_printed_counter + 1
    out.append(car)
    cars_printed_counter += 1

print(json.dumps(out))
with open("outfile.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(out))
```

Explanation: We create an `out` variable that will hold all the cars. As we loop them we create a dictionary with the values we want. But since the specs is a string we split that string by " | " to get the separate components. Then just map each component to a member in the dict. We then take that dict and append it to the `out` object. All said and done we have a list of dicts that contain all the info we need. Then we call `json.dumps()` on that list to get the json and save that to a file.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this. Check out this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-dictionary-in-python-python-dict-methods/) on how to create dicts in python

```py
import json

# this is going to store your dicts of cars
list_of_printed_cars = []

for single_car in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'cars-wrapper'):

    if cars_printed_counter == 20:
        break

    Car_Title = single_car.find('h2', class_ = 'cars__title')
    Car_Specs = single_car.find('p', class_ = 'cars__subtitle')

    # printed_car is a dictionary of the car's title and specs
    printed_car = {
        'title': Car_Title.text,
        'specs': Car_Specs.text
    }

    # this appends to a list that stores each car's title and specs
    list_of_printed_cars.append(printed_car)
    
    
# to use list_of_printed_cars, you need to convert it to a json add it to a file
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:     
    json.dump(list_of_printed_cars, f)
```

You can then use the dict of `list_of_printed_cars` as json by using `json.dumps` and saving it into a file

Comment: OP wants to store it in the json file so it's worth adding 
```with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_of_printed_cars, f)
```

Comment: ha literally just added `json.dumps()` into my answer